# Rearranging Numeric Axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot data and running into an issue with a numeric axis. It should be plotted in order:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 22, X, Y
```

Instead it's plotting like this:

```
1, 10, 11, 12... 2, 22, 3, 4..., X, Y
```

I've tried changing the column in question with `as.character, as.factor, as.numeric.` I've also checked out a few "rearrange" suggestions, but they all deal with the observations themselves, and not the axis.

What am I overlooking?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
Chr Chunk   A   B   C
1   1   3   4   4
1   2   3   4   4
1   3   3   2   4
1   4   3   4   9
2   1   3   3   4
2   2   3   4   4
2   3   3   4   4
10  1   3   4   4
10  2   3   4   4
X   1   3   4   5
X   2   3   4   8
Y   1   3   4   5
```

I'm attempting to make a series of heat plots using ggplot:

```
heat <- ggplot(data, aes(Chr, Chunk, fill = A, label = sprintf("", A))) +  geom_tile() + geom_text() + scale_fill_gradient2(high = "red")
```

Comment: Could you explain how your variable was generated?

Comment: The answer is almost always that your variable is either a character or factor, and that your attempts to change that fact have been unsuccessful. But what _specifically_ you've done wrong and how _specifically_ to fix it is impossible to say without much more detail on the actual code you're using and your data.

Comment: I've edited for clarity and provided some test data. I am guessing the X, Y at the end of the data frame is the culprit. I could remove these but would rather not, if it's possible to sort this out and keep them.

Comment: transorm your `factor` into an ordered one with the levels' order you need (so `data$Chr <- factor(data$Chr, levels=c(1:22, "X", "Y"), ordered=TRUE)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you’re dealing with character data, ggplot will simply sort your data for plotting (and character strings are lexicographically ordered, such that `'10'` comes before `'2'`). If you want to influence the order, convert your character to an ordered factor. Unfortunately this requires actually providing the order manually (but in your case that order isn’t too hard to write down):

```
data$Chr = factor(data$Chr, levels = c(1 : 22, 'X', 'Y'), ordered = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked with one tweak... strangely, when I ran it as it is above, the axis changed correctly in my plot but the observations in the body of the plot remained out of order. Why would that be? In any case, I removed 'ordered = TRUE' and it plotted correctly.